# Does an accordion-style widget in Angular2 material exist?

Tags: angular, angular-material, accordion

I am porting an old angular app to a current one.

The old app, using angular2 bootstrap, uses intensively accordion components.

Unfortunately, I can't see any similar in the Angular Material docs.

Can I get some similar effect inside the frame of the Angular2-Material widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Material2 doesn't have accordion/expansion yet. But I have seen some other Angular 2 UI libraries have it. Listing the ones I know of:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion

Angular Dart and valor-software ngx-bootstrap also have accordions

Comment: Thanks. I extracted the accordion component from the ng-bootstrap.

Comment: The expansion panel are available now:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/expansion/expansion.md